# Present blank screen, wait for key press -- how?

Tags: python, windows

'lo,

I am currently trying to code a simple routine for an experiment we are planning to run. The experiment starts by entering a subject number and creating a bunch of files. I got that part working. Next, we want the screen to go blank and display a message. Something like '*Please fill in questionnaire 1 and press [ENTER] when you are done*.'

My question is, **how do you recommend I present a blank screen with a message like that that waits for a certain key to be pressed?**

I have quite some programming experience but haven't worked with Python before so any hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance for your time!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Some extra info that might be relevant: We are running this on Windows XP (Service Pack 2) computers. The whole point of this is that the participant does not have access to the desktop or anything on the computer basically. We want the experiment to start and display a bunch of instructions on the screen that the subject has to follow without them being able to abort etc. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  you're in python 2, use [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).

If you're using python 3, use [input()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#input).

You can prompt the user for information and store the result as a string.

in python 2.x

```
response = raw_input("What would you like to do next?")
```

in python 3.x

```
response = input("What would you like to do next?")
```

Comment: Thanks, that lets me read in user input and proceed after a certain key has been pressed. The more difficult part, however, is that I don't want this to happen on the command line but in a full-screen mode that displays nothing but the prompt and doesn't let the user click anything else.

Sorry if that wasn't clear. Any ideas?

Comment: the best way I can see then would be to create your own GUI.... if you're not looking for anything fancy at all (just some basic input and event handlers) then take a look at the standard TkInter. Definitely not the best solution out there but it will allow you to create your own screen, insert different input approaches, and react to what the user chooses/selects.

Comment: np -- good luck... let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you can use functions in the *msvcrt* module.  For example, [kbhit()](http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) waits until the user presses a key.

Comment: Thanks, that lets me read in user input and proceed after a certain key has been pressed. The more difficult part, however, is that I don't want this to happen on the command line but in a full-screen mode that displays nothing but the prompt and doesn't let the user click anything else.

Sorry if that wasn't clear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To print the blank screen before putting the prompt, I used the following

```
import os
import sys

VALIDINPUT = '0'
while VALIDINPUT == '0':
    p = os.popen('clear')
    for line1 in p.readlines():
    print line1
    <put the logic for reading user input here>
    <put the logic to check for valid user input here and if the user input is valid, then
    assign 1 to VALIDINPUT>
```

This will show a blank screen and the prompt until the user provides a valid input.

Hope this helps. I used this on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input('Please fill in questionnaire 1 and press [ENTER] when you are done.')` will wait for someone to hit [enter].

Clearing the screen may be OS/environment dependent, I am not sure.