# Python, Press Any Key To Exit

Tags: python, python-2.7, key, any

So, as the title says, I want a proper code to close my python script.
So far, I've used `input('Press Any Key To Exit')`, but what that does, is generate an error.
I want a code that closes your script without using an error.

Does anyone have an idea? Google gives me the input option, but I don't want that
It closes using this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test", line 1, in <module>
    input('Press Any Key To Exit')
  File "<string>", line 0
    
   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: `input =('Press Any Key To Exit')` Do you mean `input('Press Any Key To Exit')`? The first one will do nothing. Also, try using raw_input().

Comment: the first one will do nothing, but it should not throw any error.. it will just rebind the name input to that string

Comment: @wim Agreed, that's why I assume he typed the question incorrectly and suggested trying `raw_input()`.

Comment: so, i fixed the code above,deleted the =, im using python 2.7 btw

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220943/present-blank-screen-wait-for-key-press-how

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This syntax error is caused by using [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) on Python 2, which will try to [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) whatever is typed in at the terminal prompt. If you've pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> then Python will essentially try to eval an empty string, `eval("")`, which causes a `SyntaxError` instead of the usual `NameError`.

If you're happy for "any" key to be the enter key, then you can simply swap it out for [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead:

```
raw_input("Press Enter to continue")
```

*Note that on Python 3 `raw_input` was renamed to [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).*

For users finding this question in search, [who really want to be able to press *any* key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st6-DgWeuos) to exit a prompt and not be restricted to using <kbd>enter</kbd>, you may consider to use a 3rd-party library for a cross-platform solution. I recommend the helper library [`readchar`](https://github.com/magmax/python-readchar) which can be installed with `pip install readchar`. It works on Linux, macOS, and Windows and on either Python 2 or Python 3.

```
import readchar
print("Press Any Key To Exit")
k = readchar.readchar()
```

Comment: Yep, this fixed it, but i saw someone answered this isnt available in 3.0, so if i upgrade, im stuck again?

Comment: @JoppeDnbCuyper: `raw_input` is renamed `input` in Python 3.0, so if you upgrade, you merely have to change every instance of `raw_input` to `input`

Comment: input is very dangerous in < 3.

Comment: this works great in mac to say "press enter key to continue"

Answer (score 19):

If you are on windows then the cmd `pause` command should work, although it reads 'press any key to continue'

```
import os
os.system('pause')
```

The linux alternative is `read`, a good description can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92802/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-dos-pause)

Answer (score 4):

#### `msvrct` - built-in Python module solution (windows)

I would discourage platform specific functions in Python if you can avoid them, but you could use the built-in [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) module.

```py
>>> from msvcrt import getch
>>> 
>>> 
... print("Press any key to continue...")
... _ = getch()
... exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the game, but I wrote a library a couple years ago to do exactly this. It exposes both a `pause()` function with a customizable message and the more general, cross-platform `getch()` function inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394994/233098).

Install with `pip install py-getch`, and use it like this:

```
from getch import pause
pause()
```

This prints `'Press any key to continue . . .'` by default. Provide a custom message with:

```
pause('Press Any Key To Exit.')
```

For convenience, it also comes with a variant that calls `sys.exit(status)` in a single step:

```
pause_exit(0, 'Press Any Key To Exit.')
```

[Check it out](https://github.com/joeyespo/py-getch).

Answer (score 2):

```
a = input('Press a key to exit')
if a:
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Still expects an enter or EOF, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to end by pressing any key on *nix, without displaying the key and *without pressing return*. (Credit for the general method goes to [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user).) From poking around SO, it seems like you could use the `msvcrt` module to duplicate this functionality on Windows, but I don't have it installed anywhere to test. Over-commented to explain what's going on...

```
import sys, termios, tty

stdinFileDesc = sys.stdin.fileno() #store stdin's file descriptor
oldStdinTtyAttr = termios.tcgetattr(stdinFileDesc) #save stdin's tty attributes so I can reset it later

try:
    print 'Press any key to exit...'
    tty.setraw(stdinFileDesc) #set the input mode of stdin so that it gets added to char by char rather than line by line
    sys.stdin.read(1) #read 1 byte from stdin (indicating that a key has been pressed)
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(stdinFileDesc, termios.TCSADRAIN, oldStdinTtyAttr) #reset stdin to its normal behavior
    print 'Goodbye!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am on Linux Mint 17.1 "Rebecca" and I seem to have figured it out, As you may know Linux Mint comes with Python installed, you cannot update it nor can you install another version on top of it. I've found out that the python that comes preinstalled in Linux Mint is version 2.7.6, so the following will for sure work on version 2.7.6. If you add `raw_input('Press any key to exit')` it will not display any error codes but it will tell you that the program exited with code 0. For example this is my first program. [MyFirstProgram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B463x4ZnH5QJUXNRZHp1Tk5UcWM/view?usp=sharing). Keep in mind it is my first program and I know that it sucks but it is a good example of how to use "Press any key to Exit"
BTW This is also my first post on this website so sorry if I formatted it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should post short snippets like this as a part of your answer. The editor provides the code block and inline code tools to support you. This will make your anwer easier for others to read. Read more about how to write a good answer in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DGxInfinitY from one Linux Mint fan to another.. I learned the hard way from what you tried to do. Linux Mint, and probably any Linux comes with a "system python", often both 2 and 3. It may be possible but you should not mess with it, upgrade it, downgrade it, install modules into it. Use 'virtualenv' with 'virtualenvwrapper', is convenient, keeps system Python clean. Otherwise one day, you might do something to the system Python and reboot and the gui and other stuff will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

in Windows:

```
if msvcrt.kbhit():
    if msvcrt.getch() == b'q':
        exit()
```

Comment: Please add some explanations as well.

Comment: Damn you guys came back after 6 years. I guess there’s still no correct answer ha 

Answer (score 0):

In python 3:

```
  while True: 
        #runtime..
        answer = input("ENTER something to quit: ") 
        if answer: 
            break
```

Comment: This answer is similar to others already included in the post. Also, the question is tagged Python 2.7, so you might want to specify that your answer assumes a Python 3 environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
from os import system as console

console("@echo off&cls")

#Your main code code

print("Press Any Key To Exit")
console("pause>NUL&exit")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32614573)