# How to freeze a programm

Tags: python

Hi i wanted to know how to freeze a programm in python.

```
from time import *
from sys import *
caractère = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~").lower()
a = int(input("The number of character in the password: "))
print("The password is:")
for i in range(a):
    password = ""
    cara = choice(caractère)
    print(cara, end='')
```

At the end i want to see the password but i can't because the programm the program closes automatically. Can we do it?
Thanks

Comment: For example, you may add additional `input()` at the end of the code. The program will not close until you type something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Press Any Key To Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876618/python-press-any-key-to-exit)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `input()` statement at the end of the program so it will close itself as soon as you click any key and press enter.
You can also add `time.sleep(N)` to close the program automatically after N seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any sort of if statement to close the program

```
from time import *
from sys import *
from random import choice

caractère = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~").lower()
a = int(input("The number of character in the password: "))
print("The password is:")
for i in range(a):
    password = ""
    cara = choice(caractère)
    print(cara, end='')

close_it = input("Press ENTER to exit: ")
if len(close_it) >=0:
    print("Program Ended")
```

The `close_it` will trigger after printing the password and if you press enter it will check the length of input and print `Program Ended` in any case if you give the input or not as it's going to be always true.